# Publishing WebApp to Azure App Services - Resource Groups not listed

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group

Created App Service `webAppService` under the Azure Resource Group `WebApp-RG`

When trying to publish WebApp from Visual Studio to webAppService, dialog box doesn't show up the Resource Group or AppService I created above.

Logged into Visual Studio with my account, used to create the Resource Group and AppService.

[image]

Is there any permissions / settings I have to assign / configure?

Comment: Try to reopen VS and log out you account and login again.

Comment: Try open VS as administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Close all visual studio instances
- Delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService file
- Restart Visual Studio and log in to server explorer  and see if its listing